# How to pass arguments to get_data script in AutoMLConfig

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, automl

I am trying to run AutoML experiment on my Azure Batch AI cluster. I created the following AutoMLConfig

```
AutoMLConfig(task='classification',
                         debug_log='automl_errors.log',
                         path=project_folder,
                         compute_target=compute_target,
                         data_script=project_folder + "/get_data.py",
                         exit_score=0.9985,
                         **automl_settings)
```

In the get_data python script, I would like to read the data from the default datastore. Is there a possibility to pass the mounted datastore to this script as a parameter(similar to Estimator and script_params):

```
est = Estimator(
      source_directory=script_folder,
      script_params=script_params,
      compute_target=compute_target,
      entry_script='train.py',
      conda_packages=['scikit-learn']
```

)

If not, could anyone please advise what is the best way to read the data from the default datastore in the get_data script?

Answer (score 0):

Batch AI has retired: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/batch-ai/overview-what-happened-batch-ai

We recommend you migrate to Azure ML and you can use the Dataset module from Azure ML python SDK to work with your data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-access-data

SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.dataset?view=azure-ml-py

Sample notebooks: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/work-with-data/datasets